# Measure bandwith used in transfering files with java sockets

Tags: java, file, rmi, transfer

Does anyone knows how to do this? using the java sockets

Comment: how do you define "bandwidth wasted"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by decorating socket's input and output streams.

So it might look like this:

```
class SocketWrapper extends Socket {
    private CountingInputStream input;

    @Override
    public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        if (input == null) {
            input = new CountingInputStream(super.getInputStream());
        }

        return input;
    }

    public int getInputCounter() {
        return input.getCounter();
    }

    // other stuff like getOutputStream
}

class CountingInputStream extends InputStream {
    private final InputStream inputStream;

    public CountingInputStream(InputStream inputStream) {
        this.inputStream = inputStream;
    }

    private int counter = 0;

    public int getCounter() {
        return counter;
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        counter++;
        return inputStream.read();
    }

    // other methods
}
```

Also have a look [here](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue169.html) and [here](http://java.dzone.com/news/socket-monitoring-now-using).

And finally, if you just want to know the amount of traffic, you may use sniffers.